# Problems with Maple 16 GUI on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, gui, awesome

I have installed Maple 16 (computer algebra system) to the directory /opt/maple16/ and the installation and registration progress is finished succesfully. I am running Arch Linux.

The terminal version of the program (maple) works fine, but when I start the GUI version (xmaple), the actual interface doesn't show up, however it does display the 'hint of day' window and it is possible to use, for instance, Ctrl + S for saving.

The program also opens two windows, the actual empty maple document and an empty java window.

I have tried runing it as both a normal user and as root, but that does not seem to change anything. I am using Awesome WM, but I'm not sure if that might be part of the problem.

What might the problem be and have anyone experienced the same problems? How can I debug a problem like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Maple 16 GUI is Java (which it is, judging from the documentation - [at least for an older version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmonad#Problems_with_Java_applications)), try [this procedure from the Arch wiki](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/faqs/detail.aspx?sid=33433) (refers to Xmonad but other tiling WMs might need it):

```
If you are using openjdk6, you can export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 in /etc/profile.d/openjdk6.sh.
If you are using jre7-openjdk, you can export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1 in /etc/profile.d/jre.sh.
```

So, try launching the GUI after `export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1`.

Comment: I copied the jre folder from my $JAVA_HOME directory (/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/ in my case) and replaced the jre.X86_64_LINUX in the maple directory with that, as described on the maplesoft.com page.
Then I added 'export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1' to /etc/profile.d/jre.sh as described on the Xmonad arch-wiki page.
This seems to work just fine, so thank you for your help!